# Laravel (8.x) Is there a better Eloquent query for this many-to-many filtering problem?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

### What I have

`movies` many-to-many `stars`

`movies` many-to-many `tags`

`studio` one-to-many `movies`

I pass `studio` name, `star` name and/or `tag` name as optional query strings

### What I need

- Select all `movies` with `tag` and `star` and `studio` if all 3 are passed as params
- Select all `movies` with `tag` and `star` if those 2 are passed as params
- Select all `movies` with `star` and `studio` if those 2 are passed as params
- Select all `movies` with `tag` and `studio` if those 2 are passed as params
- Select all `movies` with `tag` or `star` or `studio` if any one is passed as param
- Basically, Simplify this query

### My Possibly Stuipd code

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $movies = Movie::with('stars')->with('tags')->with('studio');

        // all matches
        // if all params are present
        if ($request->star && $request->tag && $request->studio)
            $movies->whereHas('stars', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->star);
            })->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->tag);
            })->whereHas('studio', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->studio);
            });

        // star and tag with no studio
        if ($request->star && $request->tag && !$request->studio)
            $movies->whereHas('stars', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->star);
            })->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->tag);
            });

        // star and studio with no tag
        if ($request->star && !$request->tag && $request->studio)
            $movies->whereHas('stars', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->star);
            })->whereHas('studio', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->studio);
            });

        // studio and tag with no star
        if (!$request->star && $request->tag && $request->studio)
            $movies->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->tag);
            })->whereHas('studio', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->studio);
            });

        // any one matches
        if ($request->star || $request->tag || $request->studio)
            $movies->whereHas('stars', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->star);
            })->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->tag);
            })->orWhereHas('studio', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', $request->studio);
            });

        return response($movies->paginate(20));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $movies = Movie::with('stars')->with('tags')->with('studio');

    // all matches
    // tag
    if ($request->tag)
        $movies->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', $request->tag);
        });

    // star
    if ($request->star)
        $movies->whereHas('stars', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', $request->star);
        });
    // studio
    if ($request->studio)
        $movies->whereHas('studio', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', $request->studio);
        });

    return response($movies->paginate(20));
}
```

This way you only filter your relation if its key is provided.

Comment: Ah, this was my initial approach and then I over complicated things, Thanks man, this works. This is the way. But it should be `whereHas` instead of `orWhereHas` in the studio block too, right?

Comment: Np :) yes it should be `whereHas`. I've fixed it thanks:)